# Prove the inequality $(n + 1)h_{n+1} - nh_n > r$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

> Let $h_n$ be the apothem (distance from the center to one of the sides) of a regular $n$-gon ($n \geq 3$) inscribed in a circle of radius $r$. Prove the inequality
> $$(n + 1)h_{n+1} - nh_n > r$$

---

Using trigonometry, we get $\cos (\frac{\pi}{n+1})=\frac{h_{n+1}}{r}$ and $\cos (\frac{\pi}{n})=\frac{h_{n}}{r}$. Putting these values into our inequality, we get $$(n+1) \times \cos (\frac{\pi}{n+1}) > n \cos (\frac{\pi}{n}) + 1$$ I tried induction to prove it, but it didn't work, how do I proceed to prove this inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x\cos(\pi/x)$, if $f'(x)>1$ for $x\geq3$, then $f(x+1)-f(x)>1$ and we are done.

To this end, we find $f'(x)=\cos(\pi/x)+(\pi/x)\sin(\pi/x)$. For simplicity, let $g(t)=\cos(t)+t\sin(t)$ and it is equivalent to show $g(t)>1$ for all $t\in(0,\pi/3]$.

First, note that $g(0)=1$, and also $g'(t)=t\cos(t)>0$ for $t\in(0,\pi/3]$, therefore $g(t)>1$ and the problem is solved.

Comment: how's $\cos(\pi/x)+(\pi/x)\sin(\pi/x)$ similar to $\cos(t)+t\sin(t)$? I mean I do realize you substituted $t$ in place of $\pi /x$, but how does it ensure that both if these functions would be similar, and the result that we want, if it works for the new function, would've also worked for our original function? I drew the graph of both these functions on desmos, and they look pretty different.

Comment: @zaemon_23 Thanks for the comment. First, we proved $g(t)>1$ for all $t\in(0,\pi/3]$. Then for all $x\geq3$, there exists $t\in(0,\pi/3]$ such that $\pi/x=t$, hence we have $g(\pi/x)=g(t)>1$, which is what we want. Does this clear the confusion?

Comment: Thanks a lot! A small doubt, does showing $f'(x)>k$ for all $x$ imply $f(x+1)-f(x)>k$? Intuitively, I kind of get it, that the 'rate of change of function ' is higher than $k$, hence the difference between any two point on the graph would be greater than $k$, but how do we show it rigorously?

Comment: @zaemon_23 You are welcome and good point. To make it rigorous, the idea is to fix any $p\geq3$, then compare $h_1(x)=f(p+x)$ and $h_2(x)=x+f(p)$. First we have $h_1(0)=h_2(0)$, then $h_1’(x)=f’(p+x)>1=h_2’(x)$, hence $h_1(x)>h_2(x)$ for all $x>0$. In particular, letting $x=k$ gives $f(p+k)>k+f(p)$ and here we go ;)